# z-index is causing an issue

Tags: html, css

i have created a website but now i am having 1 issue. i am unable to do click even on link and navigation.

you can take a look:
http://www.cambridgekitty.com/business-directory/
to check the real codes.

**HTML**

```
<div id="main-bg">
    <div id="left-side-logo"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrap {
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
#main-bg {
    background: url("../img/kittybg2-h.png") no-repeat scroll right top transparent;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 733px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -9999;
}
```

just add a logo on left side

```
#left-side-logo {
    background: url("../img/norwichkitty-final-logo-bg-02.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 500px;
    left: -150px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    top: -60px;
    width: 500px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

and add

```
    position: relative;
```

to #wrap. and add

```
    z-index: -9999;
```

to #main-bg.

but after doing this ... i am unable to click on logo or even navigation links.

please let me know why i am casusing this issue.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would simple change the elements I apply the different background images to. Give `#inner-wrapper` the city image background, and `#main-bg` the logo background. Then use the `background-position` property to position the logo background (currently the two zeroes in your `background` rule). Also, if you want opacity for that logo you can achieve that by simply setting it in Photoshop or whatever editor you prefer.

This solution means you don't have to deal with the `z-index` issues and makes for more hack-free and semantic mark-up, although you do have a few containers. Hope this helps :)

Comment: yes i understand now, and your way is really working with me. but with this way i need to cut the top and left side of the logo with photoshop. because if i add top and left positions to the logo. it will impliment on complete website.

Comment: If you need to put the background picture of the logo in different positions throughout different pages on the site, I'd recommend that you give the `<body>` on the page that we're discussing a class of, say, `business-directory` (because of the URL). With that class you could then alter the position of the logo only on that page, with CSS like this:
`.business-directory #main-bg {
background-position: -110px -70px;
}`

Or am I misunderstanding your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a negative `z-index` if you don't know exactly what you're doing. Use a positive value and just set `#left-side-logo`'s `z-index` to a value even higher.

Since `#wrap` has a negative `z-index`, it's placed behind the content of `#inner-wrapper` in the latter's stacking index.

See also:

- [W3C: CSS2.1: 9 Visual formatting model (Section z-index)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index)

Comment: okay..  i tried the way you told me . i add **positive z-index** to **#left-side-logo** (**z-index : 1**) but then i need to add **z-index** to **#header** (**z-index: 1**). but problem is still same. @Zeta